# Session not maintaining for the first time

Tags: php, session

i am developing a e-commerce website. The user logs in and buy a product when he checkout the page will redirect to the payment gateway. After the payment is completed it will return back to my website. This is ok. But when it is returning back the session maintained in my website get lost. This happen only for the first time. If the user again logged in and checkout the process works good and the session is maintaining.

Why does the session lost for first time.

I used `session_start()` in all the pages..

I cannot find the solutions. Kindly help..

Comment: Without code, we cannot find the solution either, we can only guess. You should post the relevant code and enable error reporting and see if you get any errors.

Comment: please give more data,like code,the different pages

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use javascript? You can create cookie to store your incoming members data. 
With Jquery and cookie plugin you can do this very easy, sure you must do login for member to create this data. Some useful links: 
http://www.jquery.com/ 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie 
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the session lost for first time.

That's hard to tell because there is not much information in your question.

Normally a session get's lost if the session identifier (or session ID in short) is not passed from one request (page) to the other.

Please see the [PHP Manual how the session ID can be passed](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php). You need to take care with your code, for example that the cookie is properly set. If the session cookie is not set, the session id will be gone and `session_start` will create a new session.